# How do I add file types to Windows 8 “File Associations” for Metro apps

Tags: windows-8, vbscript

I needed to create a new file type ".pd". I want to have the Microsoft Reader Metro app open this file type.

I've written a VBScript to manipulate and rename the files.  Now I want to open it with the Microsoft Reader Metro app.  I have two choices, 1) within the VBScript 2) have the user double click on it.  I prefer to have the VBScript open the ".pd" file for the users.

Using "How do I add file types to Windows 8 "File Associations"? does not allow me to associate a new file type listed in *Control Panel → Programs → Default Programs → Set Associations "Change program..."* with an existing Metro app - Microsoft Reader.

Everything I've seen easily associates exe files. (`gpedit.msc` on the Server, `ASSOC`, `Ftype`, etc.)

Basically I want the .PD extension to work exactly like the .PDF extension.

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: `assoc .pd=pdffile` should do what you want, if I'm not mistaken. However, I think this question is more suitable for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), since it's more about system configuration than about programming.

Comment: @Ansgar WiechersThank you - I was looking for a solution in VB Script or in the system configuration.  Let me check SuperUser also.

Comment: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "assoc .pd=pdffile"`

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers  Thanks.  I cannot get this to work in Windows 8.  Seems to work good for Windows 7.  When I try it in Windows 8 I receive the "How do you want to open this type of file (.pd)?  Look for an app in the Store."

Comment: What is the output of `ftype pdffile` and `assoc .pdf`? You need to associate the same handler that is associated with the `.pdf` extension.